# How can I make dictionary key as column of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nlp

```
!pip install -U LeXmo
from LeXmo import LeXmo
df['Dict'] = df['Content '].apply(lambda x: [LeXmo.LeXmo(x)])
```

Using this snippet , I am able to generate this

[image]

**But my desired output is**

[image]

*I want to make each dictionary key of 'Dict' as a seperate column for each row. How can I do this??*

Comment: Can you try `df['Dict'] = df['Content '].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(LeXmo.LeXmo(x)))` ?

Comment: Hi! @jezrael getting this error  ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Ooops, need `df = df.join(df['Content '].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(LeXmo.LeXmo(x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert output from `LeXmo.LeXmo(x)` to `Series`, so it create new columns if call function in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), last append to original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df['Content '].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(LeXmo.LeXmo(x))))
```